# Add record in details view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Detail view that shows information for equipment and at the bottom of the page a table of historical notes from a different table (linked via an ID field). I would like to add a button/link above that when clicked slides down a multi-line input field and a save button which allows the user to enter a new note against that item.

Does anybody have any tips or know of any tutorials that cover this.

This is my code so far

```
@model Project.Models.Asset

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Asset</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)</dt>

        <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Location)</dd>

        <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Position)</dt>

        <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Position)</dd>

        <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)</dt>

        <dd>Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)</dd>

        <dt>Serial Number</dt>

        <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SerialNo)</dd>
    </dl>

    <h4>Service History</h4>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Notes
            </th>
            <th>
                Contractor
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.ServiceHistories)
        {
            <tr>
                <td width="200px">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Notes)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContractorID)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: I have looked on the MS asp site and while there are tutorials for editing and creating records I could not find one that shows how to add records in a details view. just looking for some tips on what to search for, happy to do the reading myself.

Answer (score 0):

After posting this I did some more research, learned a little more then asked a more detailed question with examples. If it pleases the Stack Gods and in the interests any anyone who stumbles across this looking for answers to the same or similar problem please see the following thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986420/passing-parameter-across-controllers/25986499#25986499)