# Passing parameter across controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My goal is to save a record in different controller that is associated with a item in a current detail view. I have a detail view this displays a list of associated records from a different table using the following code:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Notes
        </th>
        <th>
            Contractor
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.ServiceHistories)
    {
        <tr>
            <td width="200px">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Notes)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContractorID)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", "ServiceHistories", new { id = Model.AssetID }, null)

</table>
```

At the bottom I have added an Action link to a action in a different controller to create a new Service History record for that asset by passing in the AssetID for that asset. This is the Create (POST and GET) action for Service History:

```
// GET: ServiceHistories/Create
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
{
    ViewBag.AssetID = id;
    return View();
}

// POST: ServiceHistories/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ServiceID,AssetID,Date,ContractorID,Notes")] ServiceHistory serviceHistory)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.ServiceHistories.Add(serviceHistory);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Assets", new { id = serviceHistory.AssetID });
    }

    ViewBag.AssetID = new SelectList(db.Assets, "AssetID", "Description", serviceHistory.AssetID);
    return View();

}
```

I have added (int Id) as a parameter to the Create action and assigned it to ViewBg.AssetID whic is is passed into the view ok as I can display it on the page. My problem is

My fist question is how do I use this value to replace the code below. I.e. I would like to hide the AssetID field and use the parameter ViewBag.AssetID instead.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssetID, "AssetID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("AssetID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssetID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried

```
@Html.HiddenFor(ViewBag.AssetID)
```

however I cant get it to compile error:

Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'HiddenFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

I have read a load of posts and tutorials that come close to this but I can seem to crack what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use `@Html.Hidden(ViewBag.AssetID)`, but I will post alternative answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would assign this to `ViewBag` since your model `ServiceHistory` has a property `AssetID`.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
{
  ServiceHistory model = new ServiceHistory();
  model.AssetID = id;
  return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model YourAssembly.ServiceHistory
....
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AssetID)
```

Comment: Thanks. slight mod was to change ServiceHistories model = new ServiceHistories(); to ServiceHistory model = new ServiceHistory(); I assume this is because we are only passing one record.